# how to allow duplicate keys with jackson while deserializing xml

Tags: java, xml, jackson2, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have a simple xml file structured like this with multiples **B** keys

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Example>
   <ExampleId>0000</ExampleId>
   <Name>test</Name>
   <Important1>
      <Id>
         <Number>1111111111</Number>
      </Id>
   </Important1>
   <B>
      <Name>test2</Name>
      <Important2>
         <Id>
            <Number>2222222222</Number>
         </Id>
      </Important2>
   </B>
   <B>
      <Name>test3</Name>
      <Important2>
         <Id>
            <Number>3333333333</Number>
         </Id>
      </Important2>
   </B>
</Example>
```

I need to retrieve all values from **Number** keys to a List
I tried multiple ways

```
JsonNode numberParser = xmlMapper.readTree(inputStream);
JsonNode node1 = numberParser.get("Example");
            
//first try
List<String> list =node1.findValuesAsText("Number");
            
//second try
List<String> list =new ArrayList<String>();
node1.fields().forEachRemaining(firstEntry -> {
    if(firstEntry.getKey().equals("Important1")){
            JsonNode fieldsNode = firstEntry.getValue();
            String numberFromImportant1 = fieldsNode.findValue("Number").asText();
            list.add(numberFromImportant1);
    }
    if(firstEntry.getKey().equals("B")){
            JsonNode fieldsNode = firstEntry.getValue();
            String numberFromImportant2 = fieldsNode.findValue("Number").asText();
            list.add(numberFromImportant2);
    }
});
```

However , it seems that jackson takes only the last value from **Number** if it encounters duplicate **B** nodes while deserializing
Any way to prevent that and allow Jackson to take duplicate into account as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is retrieve the value for the `node` number, then consider using xpath. Appending double forward space to the XML node will search for the node (in the entire xml file). E.g: `//Number`

**For example:**

```
Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(inputStream);
this.clean(xmlDocument);
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "//Number";
nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```